# Rails 4 fields_for not displaying or updating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a nested relationship where dashboard has many rewards, and I am trying to add a fields_for to the page in order to edit the rewards. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be working and I don't know why.

Here's what I have.

Dashboard model:

```
class Dashboard < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :manager

    has_many :rewards
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :rewards, allow_destroy: true
end
```

Rewards model:

```
class Reward < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :dashboard
end
```

Dashboard controller:

```
class DashboardsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_manager!

    # Requires user to be signed in 
    def index
        @dashboards = Dashboard.all
    end

    def new
        @dashboard = Dashboard.new
    end

    def edit
        @dashboard = Dashboard.find(params[:id])
    end

    def create
        @dashboard = Dashboard.new(dashboard_params)
        @dashboard.save

        if @dashboard.save
            redirect_to dashboard_path(@dashboard)
        else
            render :action => new
        end
    end

    def update
      @dashboard = Dashboard.find(params[:id])

      if @dashboard.update(dashboard_params)
        redirect_to :action => :show
      else
        render 'edit'
      end
    end

    def show
        @dashboard = Dashboard.find(params[:id])
    end

    def destroy
        @dashboard = Dashboard.find_by_id(params[:id])

        if @dashboard.destroy
            redirect_to dashboards_path
        end
    end

    private 
    def dashboard_params 
        args = params.require(:dashboard).permit(:title, :description, :rewards, {rewards_attributes: [ :id, :title, :referralAmount, :dashboardid, :selected, :_destroy] } )
        args
    end

end
```

Form in dashboards view:

```
  <%= form_for :dashboard, url: dashboard_path(@dashboard), method: :patch do |f| %>   
      <% if @dashboard.errors.any? %>
        <div id="error_explanation">
          <h2>
            <%= pluralize(@dashboard.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited
            this dashboard from being saved:
          </h2>
          <ul>
            <% @dashboard.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
              <li><%= msg %></li>
            <% end %>
          </ul>
        </div>
      <% end %>
      <p>
        <%= f.label :title %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :title %>
      </p>
      <p>
        <%= f.label :description %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :description %>
      </p>

      <%= f.fields_for :rewards do |reward| %>

        <%= reward.label :title %><br>
        <%= reward.text_field :title %>
        <%= reward.check_box :_destroy %>
        <%= reward.label :_destroy, "Remove reward" %>

      <% end %>

      <p>
        <%= f.submit %>
      </p>
  <% end %>
```

I went ahead and manually added rewards to the database through the rails console and it worked beautifully, but they are not showing up on the page. They will show up if I iterate through them like so

```
<% if @dashboard.rewards.any? %>
<ul>
<% @dashboard.rewards.each do |reward| %>
  <li><%= reward.title %></li>
  <li><%= reward.referralAmount %></li>
<% end %>
</ul>
<% else %>
  <p>no rewards</p>
<% end %>
```

However the fields_for does not display the rewards or their content and resultingly allow one to edit them.

Let me know if you need further information/code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to modify your:

**View**:

```
  <% if @dashboard.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2>
        <%= pluralize(@dashboard.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited
        this dashboard from being saved:
      </h2>
      <ul>
        <% @dashboard.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
          <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <%= form_for @dashboard, url: dashboard_path(@dashboard) do |f| %>
  ........
  <% end %>
```

**Controller** (*has_many relat*ionship):

```
def new
    @dashboard = Dashboard.new
    @dashboard.rewards.build
end

private 
def dashboard_params 
  params.require(:dashboard).permit(:title, :description,
    rewards_attributes: [ 
    :id,
    :title,
    :referralAmount,
    :dashboardid,
    :selected,
    :_destroy
  ])        
end
```

You don't have to set the **method: patch** if form.
Once you got in edit page, Rails will use the **update action** in controller when form submission.

To check it, run **rake routes**,
you will see somsthing like this:

```
PATCH  /dashboards/:id(.:format)                dashboards#update
PUT    /dashboards/:id(.:format)                dashboards#update
```

Comment: The controller was already set up that way. The fix, however was in your answer so I'm marking it correct. For anyone else, I had to change <%= form_for :dashboard, url: dashboard_path(@dashboard), method: :patch do |f| %>   to 
<%= form_for @dashboard, url: dashboard_path(@dashboard) do |f| %>

Comment: Happy to helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting an "@rewards" instance variable in your dashboards edit method (where @rewards = @dashboard.rewards). Then replace :rewards with @rewards.

**Edit:**

I believe my initial answer is inapproriate for your exact question (while it would be helpful on say the page to show a specific dashboard and its rewards). The answers above are on the right track re:

1. refining your params method per @aldrien.h;
2. Adding @santosh dadi's suggestion of

   ```
   @dashboard.rewards.build
   ```

   (assuming you only want one rewards fields on a form for "new")
3. Finally though, to avoid making fake information for a new rewards form, adding to the top of your Dashboards model:

   ```
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :rewards, reject_if: lambda {|attributes| attributes['title'].blank?}
   ```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#nested-forms

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, I get
undefined method `title' for #<Reward::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007fa7512b0250>

Comment: I tried to use @ rewards = @ dashboard.rewards.all as well, and it did not work, but when I use @ rewards = @ dashboard.rewards.first , the first reward object does show but its not editable in any case, any idea how to expand on this?

Answer (score 0):

In controller you need to give build

```
 def new
    @dashboard = Dashboard.new
    @dashboard.rewards.build
 end
```

"build" is just create a new object in memory so that the view can take this object and display something, especially for a form.

Hope it helps for you

Comment: This didn't appear to have any effect

Answer (score 0):

You should build object before nested form. You can add whatever you want that object.

Try it in controller;

```
def new
  @dashboard = Dashboard.new
  3.times do
    @dashboard.build_reward
  end
end
```